# Diophantine Equation $a^6+b^6+c^6=d^6$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Within the literature on Diophantine equations there seems to be very little on the $6,1,3$ equation:

$$a^6+b^6+c^6=d^6\quad\quad(1)$$

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation6thPowers.html), for example, simply records that there are no known solutions of $6.1.n$ equations for $n \leq 6$. The former Euler Project searching for solutions of equations in equal sums of like powers showed $6,1,5$ at the top of its [most wanted list](http://euler.free.fr/wanted.htm) but did not mention $6,1,3$.

One way of looking at the $6,1,3$ equation is as a special case of the much more familiar $3,1,3$ equation:

$$w^3+x^3+y^3=z^3\quad\quad(2)$$

in which each of the terms is also a square. It may be considered relevant that there are known solutions of $(2)$ in which *two* or *three* of the terms are square, the smallest respectively being:

$$(1^2)^3 + 6^3 + 8^3 = (3^2)^3\quad\quad(3)$$

$$118^3 + (15^2)^3 + (18^2)^3 = (19^2)^3\quad\quad(4)$$

***Question***: Are there any discussions in the literature of either:

1. direct strategies for searching for solutions of $(1)$;
2. research seeking a proof that $(1)$ has no non-trivial solutions?

By a direct strategy I mean one which addresses 6,1,3 itself, rather than one which searches for $6,1,n$ for higher $n$ with the remote possibility of finding a solution in which some of the terms are zero.  An example of a direct strategy would be to take the following parametric solution of $(2)$:

$$(9s^4)^3 + (3s(t^3-3s^3))^3 + (t(t^3-9s^3))^3 = (t^4)^3$$

which already has two square terms, and to try to find values of $s$ and $t$ such that the other two terms are also square.

Comment: Might be related: [All solutions of the Diophantine equation $a^6+b^6=c^6+d^6+e^6+f^6+g^6$ for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g<250000$ found with a distributed Boinc project](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.0462.pdf). So in your case we have $$b=f=g=0$$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476131/does-a6b6-c6d3-have-a-non-trivial-solution) may be of interest.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII  Thanks.  I've added an example which is a generalisation of the identity for $a^3+b^3=1+c^3$ in your post.

Comment: You also missed $4^3 + 17^3 + 22^3 = 25^3$ for which two of the terms are square. Same with the equation, $49^3 + 84^3 + 102^3 = 121^3$ and $9^3 + 58^3 + 255^3 = 256^3$, but $9^3 + 58^3 = 22^3 + 57^3$, so does that count? Also, another solution is $118^3 + 225^3 + 324^3 = 361^3$.

Comment: @user477343  Yes, there are many specific solutions of (2) with two squares - it's not hard to find them.  The relevance of a parametric solution which guarantees two squares is that it opens the possibility of searching for values of the parameters that make the other two terms square too

Comment: Oh, and I found another one: $1^3 + 71^3 + 138^3 = 144^3$ to replace the last one I mentioned (which was the one you found anyway).

Comment: @MrPie There are infinitely many primitive solutions such that $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$ involve **three** squares. See second answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476131/4781) of mine, but I think the answer there would be informative for this one. To find possible solutions to,

$$a^6+b^6+c^6 = d^6\tag{i}$$

one way suggested by Piquito is to look at,

$$a^2+b^2+c^2 = d^2\tag{ii}$$

and make ***all terms cubes***. Turns out that, except for a single term (so close!), we can do so *infinitely* using elliptic curves. A second way suggested by the OP is to look at,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = d^3\tag{iii}$$

and make ***all terms squares***. Turns out that, again except for a single term, we can do so *infinitely* still using elliptic curves. Examples for both are,

$$\quad 42^6+9^{12}+10^{12} = 1134865^2$$
$$25402^3+3^{18}+138^6 = 13^{12}$$

(*It's curious how high powers are involved!*) For the first approach, see this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2784883/4781) by Old Peter.  For the second approach, consider the well-known identity,

$$(1-9t^3)^3+(3t^2)^6+(3t-9t^4)^3=1$$

To address the OP's question, we have to set *both* the first and third terms as squares. That might be difficult, but perhaps it is feasible for just one. Choosing the third term,

$$3t-9t^4 = y^2$$

which, after transforming to Weierstrass form, is an *elliptic curve* and has **infinitely** rational points. The first point is $t_1=3/13$ which yields the second equality below,

$$\color{blue}{118^3 + 15^6 + 18^6 = 19^6}\tag1$$
$$25402^3+27^6+138^6 = 169^6\tag2$$

where $169 = 13^2$ and are the *1st* and *2nd* smallest primitives with $\text{GCD}(b,c,d)=1.$ (I did a small exhaustive search with $d<200.$) Another solution is $t_3 = \frac{(73047\sqrt{3})^2}{48795650749}$, plus an *infinite* more, though there may be points of smaller height.

---

**Edit 1**: Thanks to **Dan Fulea** who found the smaller height $t_2 = \frac{(92\sqrt{3})^2}{36985}$ which yields,

$$\small{−3578403985453454495^3+1934260992^6+335389956^6=1367890225^6}\tag3$$

and $1367890225=36985^2.$ Whether these 3 solutions are the smallest primitives with $d<10^{10}$ is rather doubtful, since the first solution is *sporadic*, does not belong to the infinite family, and there may be more sporadics.

---

**Edit 2:** All of Dan's seven $t_n$ in the comments below have the form $t_n = \frac{(p\sqrt{3})^2}{q}$. If this is always the case, then,

$$\; -a+d^2 \equiv 0 \text{ mod }3^5$$

But this is also obeyed by the first sporadic solution $ -118+19^2 = 3^5.$ So whether this is a valid congruence for all primitive $a^3+b^6+c^6 = d^6$ is unknown, and whether it has other *sporadic* solutions (like the blue equation) is also unknown.

---

**Edit 3:** Thanks to Seiji Tomita for extending the search radius! He searched for integer $a=(-b^6-c^6+d^6)^{1/3}$ with $b<c<d<1000$ but found **no** new primitive solution with $\text{GCD}(b,c,d)=1.$ Still, there is *large* gap between $d=10^3$ and $d=10^{10}$, so there might be sporadic solutions in between.

Comment: see https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-05/S0002-9904-1949-09219-4/S0002-9904-1949-09219-4.pdf

Comment: Thanks you for the comment i'm a bit fool to doesn't see that . BUT see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-30/issue-3/On-Equal-Sums-of-Sixth-Powers/10.1216/rmjm/1021477246.full

Comment: @ErikSatie I have that already. And a lot of others as well.

Comment: Hope you find you wish .

Comment: Let us start with the equation $3t-9t^4=y^2$. Multiply by $9/t^4$. We obtain the form:$$\left(\frac 3t\right)^3 -81 =\left(\frac {3y}{t^2}\right)^2\ .$$So we have a passage to the elliptic curve in Weierstraß form $Y^2 =X^3-81$, rank one, no non-trivial torsion. The generator is $P=(X_1,Y_1)=(13,46)$, let $nP$ be $(X_n,Y_n)$, so we associate $t_n=3/X_n$. The first few values for $t$ are $$\begin{aligned}t_1 &= 3/13 \\
t_2 &= 25392/36985 \\
t_3 &= 16007592627/48795650749 \\
t_4 &= 149981896780909248/16403197409261230945 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: ... and then$$\small\begin{aligned}t_5 &= 139526995342454427332064744723/937546524954004840332202751773 \\
t_6 &= 6651327657774777688130149604606534531866800/10472874675613810820325511909648132551914809 \\
t_7 &= 21718752458202864475757548521660349909333225324186217490723\\&\qquad/\ 49878720992454287008991380420642198484524993272979598050093 \end{aligned}$$

Comment: So we obtain:$$-3578403985453454495^3 + 1934260992^6 + 335389956^6 = 36985^{12}\ .$$(Solution obtained inserting $t=t_2$. Note that the solution with $169^6$ on the R.H.S. above is also a "higher power", $13^{12}$. And for the next solutions...) +1

Comment: @dan_fulea Thanks so much for this! Now I have 8 solutions to test the congruence I observed (which holds true for all 8), plus we now have three "smallish" solutions. A productive post.

Comment: @Tito I did a brute force search, but didn't find a solution with $200 < d < 1000$.

Comment: @Tomita: Thanks so much! I will modify the post and add your search radius, credited to you. I'll be posting more questions about "equal sums of like powers", a topic we both like, and I'll notify you when I do so.  :)

Comment: @dan_fulea You may like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4779869/4781) on elliptic curves for $a^4+b^4 = c^4+d^4$.

Answer (score 3):

**COMMENT** (This is not an answer!)

The identity $(2xz)^2+(2yz)^2+(z^2-x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$ gives the general solution of $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=W^2$ so one has the necessary condition with parameters $x,y,z$
$$\begin{cases}a^3=2xz\\b^3=2yz\\c^3=z^2-x^2-y^2\\d^3=x^2+y^2+z^2\end{cases}$$ This could be a good first step to get an answer.

(Follow the **COMMENT**).- By the way, if
$$A_1=a^5+10a^4-8a^3+16a^2+64a-32\\A_2=a^5-10a^4-8a^3-16a^2+64a+32\\A_3=-a^5+8a^4+8a^3-16a^2+80a+32\\A_4=-a^5-8a^4+8a^3+16a^2+80a-32$$ then we have for all real parameter $a$ the identity
$$a(6a^4+24a^2+96)^3=A_1^3+A_2^3+A_3^3+A_4^3$$ Consequently, making $a=n^3$, one has for all natural $n$ an identity:

$$X_1^3+X_2^3+X_3^3+X_4^3=X_5^3$$  where each $X_i$ has degree $15$.

Comment: +1  That look's promising.  It implies (among other things) that $c^3$, $z^2$ and $d^3$ are in arithmetic progression, which is quite possible, eg $(c,z,d)=(1,78,23) \implies (c^3,z^2,d^3) = (1,6084, 12167)$.

Comment: Good luck. It would be desirable to establish whether or not there are an infinity of solutions.